# Did this idle query cause my create unique index command to lock up?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique-index

I had an open connection from Matlab to my postgres server, and the last query was `insert into table_name ...`, which had state `idle` when I look at the processes on the database server using:

```
SELECT datname,pid,state,query FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

I tried to create a unique index on `table_name` and it was taking a very long time, with no discernable CPU usage for the `pgadmin` process. When I closed the connection from Matlab, the query dropped out of `pg_stat_activity`, and the unique index was immediately built.

Was the idle query the reason why it took so long to build the index?

Answer (score 2):

No, a session in state “idle” does not hold any locks and cannot block anything. It's “idle in transaction” sessions that usually are the problem, because they tend to hold locks over a long time. Such sessions are almost always caused by an application bug.

To investigate problems like that, look at the view `pg_locks`. A hanging `CREATE INDEX` statement will usually hang acquiring the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table to be indexed. You should see that by a value of `FALSE` in the `granted` column of `pg_locks`. Then figure out which backend (`pid`) has a lock on the table in question, an you have the culprit(s).